# Hot add options for VCD using Terraform

Tags: terraform

I've only started with Terraform and I'm trying to integrate its use into our VCD (VMware vCloud Director) environment.

I've found the provider config and have created a vapp and vm using Terraform but don't see any options to enable memory and cpu hot add. Is this something that can be done?

Comment: What is VCD? And can you show your Terraform code so far and specifically how it doesn't achieve what you want to do.

Comment: VMware vCloud Director ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to provide the details, such as the terraform code you run with, what's the plan output.

I went through the offical document, and this resource supports cpu/memory.

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name             = "terraform-test"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

  num_cpus = 2
  memory   = 1024
  guest_id = "other3xLinux64Guest"

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 20
  }
}
```

So what resource are you talking about?

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/index.html